# Why are my local notifications not appearing on my actual device? (iPhone 5c)

Tags: ios, objective-c, notifications, uilocalnotification

Local notifications will appear in simulator but not in my handheld device when i transfer the program.

This is my Action button that will start a timer and depending on the value of a slider a notification should come up every num amount of minutes.

```
- (IBAction)StartTimer:(id)sender {
checker = 1;
[self pressed];
NSString *title = @"Shower Alarm";
NSString *message = @"Your alarm will start now";
NSString *okAlert = @"Ok";
UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:title message:message preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
UIAlertAction *okButton = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:okAlert style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:nil];

[alert addAction:okButton];
[self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];

check.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Showering In Progress..."];
//[self Timer];

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

    num1 = num*60.0;
    _ShowerTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:num1
                                                    target:self
                                                  selector:@selector(notification)
                                                  userInfo:nil
                                                   repeats:YES];});}
```

This is my Notification method being called by the timer @selector

```
-(void)notification{

//NSDate *alarmTime = [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:num];
UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];

UILocalNotification *notifyAlarm = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

// get current date/time
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
// display in 12HR/24HR (i.e. 11:25PM or 23:25) format according to User Settings
[dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
NSString *currentTime = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:today];
//NSLog(@"User's current time in their preference format:%@",currentTime);

notifyAlarm.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:1.0];
notifyAlarm.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
notifyAlarm.repeatInterval = 0;
notifyAlarm.soundName = @"";
notifyAlarm.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Notified at %@",currentTime];
[app scheduleLocalNotification:notifyAlarm];}
```

I have asked for permission in my didFinishLaunching method also. I read something about didReceiveLocalNotification but does that effect my device and not the simulator? I can lock my simulator and i will still get notifications, but my device won't get any notifications.

Comment: Can you please check if your device is not on Do Not Disturb setting. If it is remove it and then try.

Comment: I see that you are scheduling notifications just 1 second after current time. Could you please try with `presentLocalNotificationNow` instead.

Comment: Instead of having a timer, call **[self notification]** and modify notifyAlarm.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:1.0];
 to have 60 seconds like this **notifyAlarm.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:60.0];**. When putting application in background on phone it might be close. Scheduling a timer will make fire even if application is being closed or freezed from puttin in background. Did that work?

Comment: @SilviuSt the app is an alarm, so the user picks a interval and th timer is used to know what interval to send the notification

Comment: @Abhinav okay so the notifications work when im INSIDE the app, but if i press the home button or lock the phone nothing appears or notifies me.

Comment: @HamdiHmimy But have you tried? Is the same stuff only that it should work

Comment: @SilviuSt it works, but only after 60 seconds it doesnt send notifications in intervals, how can i send it in intervals.

Comment: Wat intervals? I write you a solution and you ask for other things. I can't write your code. You should google if not know something

Comment: I have made an answer.if that was the solution mark it as correct. As if for your other question, make another question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of having a timer, call

```
[self notification]
```

and modify

```
notifyAlarm.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:1.0];
```

to have 60 seconds like this

```
notifyAlarm.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:60.0];
```

. When putting application in background on phone it might be close. Scheduling a timer will make fire even if application is being closed or freezed from puttin in background. Did that work?